# Trying to run statistical tests in R but struggling as I am new to the language

Tags: r, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, cross-validation, references

Good Day,  I believe this issue is more of a lack of understand of R (as I have never used it till recently) than anything else.  What I am looking for is references, or documents to help me solve my problem.

I have a set of data that I created a pair of decision tress on (pruned and unpruned).  I did this using Weka and 10-fold cross-validation.  There was no problem here.  I got a higher accuracy for the pruned tree and I have individual accuracies for each of the ten folds.

I am now working on doing statistical testing to these two trees, I want to do a T-Test and the Wilcoxon test.  It was suggested that I use the

```
experimentalComparison()
```

function for the cross-validation, but I can already do this in weka.  For the actual stat tests I can do the t-test similar to the example [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/two-sample-students-t-test-1/) by manually feeding the values from the individual fold-tests similar to what is in the code in that example.  The Wilcoxon test is what is throwing me off.  I found [this example](http://www.r-bloggers.com/wilcoxon-mann-whitney-rank-sum-test-or-test-u/) but I was told to use the function

```
compAnalysis()
```

in the DMwR package.  I looked at the [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/DMwR/docs/compAnalysis) for it and I do not quite understand it.  It says to feed in the results from `experiemntalComparison()` for the first value, which means I should be doing my cross-validation with that function (vs. weka).  I am not understanding how to get the "trees" I made in weka this function.  The [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/DMwR/docs/experimentalComparison) refers to some usermade class `cv.rpartXse`.  So I am stumped, being new to this language, on how to accomplish these statistical tests via R.

Answer (score 2):

Recommend the following from the http://cran.r-project.org/ site.  Select manuals from the left menu bar and open **An Introduction to R**.  While this may cover more than you want, it is kept current with the latest released R core package.

Now select contrib from the left menu bar.  Here I suggest you look at several of the offered documents until you find one whose presentation is the clearest for you.

As a side note.  If you have two data vectors `x` and `y` then then
     t.test(x,y) will do the two sample t test.  Input ?t.test for information about the options.

And wilcox.test(x,y) will do a two sample wilcoxen test.  Again use ?wilcox.test for details about the options.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I saw these earlier and they look quite simple, much easier than the suggested compAnalysis() and experimentalComparison() functions I was suggested to use.  Do you know why those might have been of any use?

Comment: Without data context information, I am assuming that you were being directed to bootstrap/jackknife/resampling or simulation to provide parameter estimates.

Comment: Thanks, our data that we were provided was in a big .arff file.  That's more weka where I am analyzing it and feeding the answers manually into R.